# Method for get base URI

Tags: c#

How can I improve the following code?

```
private const string OAuthTokenUri = "oauth2/token";

private static string GetOAuthTokenUri(string uriAddress)
{
   var uri = new Uri(uriAddress);
   var baseUri = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
   var s = new Uri(new Uri(baseUri), OAuthTokenUri);
   return s.ToString();
}
```

I call `GetOAuthTokenUri()` like:

```
var oauthTokenUri = GetOAuthTokenUri("http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx");
```

As a result I'm getting

```
http://www.example.com/oauth2/token
```

Please help to improve `GetOAuthTokenUri`

Comment: So what's your issue? Isn't it working like you expect it to?

Comment: All works but I want to improve it. This is CodeReview, just for review but not for fix bugs

Comment: I don't really see the point of posting a fairly short method and asking for improvements. I'd say that `s` is a bad variable name and I don't see the point of assigning it (can't you `return new Uri(new Uri(baseUri), OAuthTokenUri).ToString());`), but there's not much of substance here to warrant a review.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
private const string OAuthTokenUri = "/oauth2/token";

private static string GetOAuthTokenUri(string uriAddress)
{
   Uri result = null;
   return Uri.TryCreate(new Uri(uriAddress), OAuthTokenUri, out result) ? result.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

Please note the slash I have added to OAuthTokenUri.

Comment: Why return `string.Empty`? Why even use `Uri.TryCreate` to avoid throwing an exception?

Comment: Why can't it return string.Empty? Why must it throw an exception? I don't think it's something we should discuss in this question.

Comment: Because now you need to check whether you get back `null` or even worse `string.Empty`. IMHO this is a case where I'd want to get an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Well, if an exception is thrown you may also have to handle it. Otherwise the whole program may stop working when an invalid $uriAddress is passed to this function, which IMHO is not a robust design. So do you prefer to handle exceptions or to check the return value? I prefer the latter.